# Property editor.tokenColorCostimazitions is not allowed error - VsCode

Tags: visual-studio-code

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {   
        "[Default Dark+]": {
            "editor.selectionHighlightBackground": "#3b3b3b",
            "editor.tokenColorCostimazitions": {

            }
```

gives an error following

```
Property editor.tokenColorCostimazitions is not allowed.
```

I am trying to change the Variables'/Functions' colors etc.
Is this method removed or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: use `"editor.tokenColorCustomizations"` as main key

Comment: But is there a way to separate properties' and variables' colors?

Comment: use the Developer Tool for Scope inspection, if it has the same scope it will get the same color, Search SO for `editor.tokenColorCostimazitions`

Answer (score 1):

use "editor.tokenColorCustomizations" as main key

Comment: better as a comment, else please expand your answer

Answer (score 1):

This page has all you need to understand how to change some syntax highlighting colors (ie, change the color of a class or property) but it's not presented in a way that makes sense until after you've already answered the question, so this is my attempt to organize all the information contained on this page to make it easier to digest.

You first need to edit `settings.json` directly, you can open this file by opening the Command Palette (in macOS the keyboard shortcut is `CMD + SHIFT + P`) and running this command:

```
View -> Command Palette
```

Then you'll want to add the `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` key (if it doesn't already exist) and add the theme you want to customize, so your `settings.json` file should be setup something like this:

```
{
  "editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Default Dark+]": {
      // all your syntax color customizations will go in this block
    }
}
```

It looks like VSCode has a few easy to set values like `comments` and `strings`, but everything else has to go through the `textMateRules` key. So, if you wanted to customize comment, string, and class colors, your settings could look something like this:

```
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
  "[Default Dark+]": {
    "comments": "#00FF00",
    "strings": "#FF0000",
    "textMateRules": [
      {
        "scope": "entity.name.type.class",
        "settings": {
          "foreground": "#0000FF"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But how do you know `entity.name.type.class` is the scope you need to change the class color? Well, you can run this command in the Command Palette:

```
Developer: Inspect Editor Tokens and Scopes
```

And that will show you all the highlighting information about whatever token you click on. You'll want to pay extra special attention to the `foreground` value.

That should be enough to get you started customizing your chosen theme.